# Modify Ruby OptionParser error message

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I'm learning to use Ruby's OptionParser class. How can I improve the quality of the parsers error messages? Here is an example of an flag with a mandatory option that must be one of `hour`, `day`, `week`, or `month`.

```
opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{$0} [options] username"

  times = [:hour, :day, :week, :month]
  opts.on('-t', '--time=TIME', times,
          'Show messages from the last TIME (defaults to weeks)', "Avaliable options are (#{times.join(', ')})") do |time|
    o.time = time
  end
end
```

Here are some example outputs.

```
$ ./script -t
./scraper.rb:195:in `main': missing argument: -t (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
from ./scraper.rb:210:in `<main>'

$ ./script -t not_a_value
./scraper.rb:195:in `main': invalid argument: -t not_a_value (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
from ./scraper.rb:210:in `<main>'
```

I'd like the error to mention the acceptable values, something like `invalid option for -t 'not_a_value', valid options are hour, day, week, month`

Answer (score 2):

I do it in following way:

```
begin
    parser.parse! ARGV
rescue OptionParser::InvalidArgument => e
#    puts e.instance_variables
#    puts e.args
#    puts e.reason
    if e.args.include? '-t'
        STDERR.puts "Invalid value of parameter -t. Availible options: #{t_options}"
        puts parser.help
        exit 1
    end
    STDERR.puts e
end
```

If parameter -t is missing printout following. Otherwise print default error message. Left some commented out "puts" lines which my help you to find additional helpful stuff inside the exception data.

Answer (score 1):

OptionParser doesn't really help you much with this, but you can implement it yourself without too much trouble and still be DRY. Just check correctness yourself and throw an error if needed.

```
times = [:hour, :day, :week, :month]
opts.on('-t', '--time=TIME',
    'Show messages from the last TIME (defaults to weeks)',
    "Available options are <#{times.join ', '}>") do |time|
  times.include?(time.to_sym) or 
    raise OptionParser::ParseError.new("time must be one of <#{times.join ', '}>")
  o.time = time
end
```

It's also nice to make the output a little cleaner:

```
  begin
    p.parse!(ARGV)
  rescue OptionParser::ParseError => e
    puts e
    exit 1
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is as simple as:

```
opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{$0} [options] username"

  times = [:hour, :day, :week, :month]
  begin
    opts.on('-t', '--time=TIME', times,
      'Show messages from the last TIME (defaults to weeks)', "Avaliable options are (#    {times.join(', ')})") do |time|
    o.time = time
    rescue OptionParser::MissingArgument, OptionParser::InvalidArgument
      $stderr.print "Usage: -t <argument> where argument in [:hour, :day, :week, :month]"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that. Exceptions aren't thrown until opt_parser.parse! is called so that begin..rescue block doesn't help.

Comment: @everett1992 so rescue around the parse! call.

Comment: Then you would have to string search the exception message to find which flag was invalid (My actual code has multiple flags, this example just has one for brevity). It's an option, but one that seems kludgey. I'd expect error messages on bad options to be a common use for an options parser, and I'm surprised they aren't supported.